# WCF Service Named Pipes

Tags: c#, wcf, service-reference

I have created a WCF service with the following configuration:

```
<behaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFServiceNamedPipe">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceNamedPipe" name="WCFDemo2.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
        name="WCFNamedPipeEndPoint" contract="WCFDemo2.IService1" />

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/NamedPipeExample" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

  </service>
</services>
```

When I run this exe I don't get any errors. Now I try to add service reference to the client with the following address:

```
net.pipe://localhost/NamedPipeExample
```

I get an error:

> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.pipe://localhost/NamedPipeExample'.
>   There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d).
>   There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d).
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Any suggestion which would help me rectify it?

Comment: bindingConfiguration is empty

Comment: That's for the response, I added the binding configuration but it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You do not expose any metadata so that client could retrieve service's definition?